# Run docker inside ubuntu container

Tags: docker, ubuntu

2 days I try to run the docker inside an ubuntu container:

1. `docker run -it ubuntu bash`
2. Install docker by instruction of https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/ or/and https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04
3. Finally I have installed docker:

```
root@e65411d2b70a:/# docker -v
Docker version 19.03.6, build 369ce74a3c
```

4. But when I try to run `docker run hello-world` have some problem

```
root@5ac21097b6f6:/# docker run hello-world
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

In service list not docker:

```
root@5ac21097b6f6:/# service docker start
docker: unrecognized service
root@5ac21097b6f6:/# service  --status-all
 [ - ]  apparmor
 [ + ]  cgroupfs-mount
 [ - ]  dbus
 [ ? ]  hwclock.sh
 [ - ]  procps
 [ ? ]  ubuntu-fan
```

When try to run `dockerd`:

```
root@5ac21097b6f6:/# dockerd    
INFO[2020-04-23T07:01:11.622627006Z] Starting up                                  
INFO[2020-04-23T07:01:11.624389266Z] libcontainerd: started new containerd process  pid=154
INFO[2020-04-23T07:01:11.624460438Z] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2020-04-23T07:01:11.624477203Z] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2020-04-23T07:01:11.624532871Z] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2020-04-23T07:01:11.624560679Z] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2020-04-23T07:01:11.664827037Z] starting containerd                           revision= version="1.3.3-0ubuntu1~18.04.2"
ERRO[2020-04-23T07:01:11.664943052Z] failed to change OOM score to -500            error="write /proc/154/oom_score_adj: permission denied"
...
INFO[2020-04-23T07:01:11.816951247Z] stopping event stream following graceful shutdown  error="context canceled" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: iptables failed: iptables -t nat -N DOCKER: iptables v1.6.1: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
 (exit status 3)
```

Not understand why `Permission denied` if user `root`.

Install `sudo` and add root to the group, but it's not help.

```
apt-get install sudo
usermod -a -G sudo root
```

- `sudo dockerd` have the save problem.

How to make work docker inside ubuntu container? Do you have ideas?

ps. I know about docker-in-docker, I need exactly docker inside ubuntu-container

pss. I know about `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` - but needed independent the docker service inside ubuntu-container.

Comment: Please think hard about why you need to do this.  Running a separate Docker daemon inside a container is difficult, potentially confusing, and generally discouraged; targeting the host's Docker daemon makes it very easy to root the entire host.  Redesigning your application to not directly need `docker` commands would be better if that's at all an option.

Comment: I understand your concern, and I have reconsidered my attitude towards Docker. I think about docker how about vm, but in real it's not a true. The essence of what was written in the documentation came to me just now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When running docker in docker, the container must use the docker engine on your host.

Here is a simple working setup:

1) Create a dockerfile with docker CLI installed. I am using the official compose image, so you also have docker-compose

```
FROM docker/compose:1.25.5
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh"]
```

2) When running it, mount the docker sock

```
$ docker build -t dind .
$ docker run --rm -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock dind
```

Form within the container, you now have docker. Try running `docker ps`

Comment: but the OP wants to run it inside an ubuntu container. How can we use docker inside a container that is not specifically the docker or dind container?

Comment: to anyone confused: the image you run doesn't have to be the docker image, it can be any image as long as you add this flag: `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do docker in docker without `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` then I am afraid that there is no good way to do this.
Sharing the docker socket from host is the classic way to make docker containers run within another docker container.

Comment: this is what I am using to run docker in docker and I've had it in prod for years